# DataBase with gps routes

Tags: php, sql, database, gps

I need to link a database with a website, and this database has to store the running course that the user did. How do I go about this? what is the best way to store such information. I get how I can store location, but I dont know how to store like a 2 mile route.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I never did something like this, but I think a possible way would be to store more Locations, like every 10m or something like this. All these points together create the 2-mile route.